# Reactjs - Passing a component into innerHTML, the right way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple method which updates the state:

```
handleResponse(showMessage, message) {
    this.setState({
        Form: {},
        Result: {
            showMessage: showMessage,
            message: message
        }
    });
}
```

I have a toggle component which is listening for state changes:

```
<ToggleDisplay
    className="resMessage"
    show={this.state.Result.showMessage}
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: this.state.Result.message
    }}
/>
```

The string I want to pass in is e.g.

```
Please <NavLink to="/Register">Click Here</NavLink>
```

So, passing a component into a component which needs to render.

I tried using template literals around the component but that just caused all sorts of IDE errors so clearly wrong.

The question is, is there a better way than `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as it just feels wrong and doesn't allow a component to be passed in anyway.

I know I could pass in

```
Please <a href="/Register">Click Here</a>
```

But this is useless as it goes against the SPA route and still feels wrong.

I've also tried:

```
<ToggleDisplay
    className="resMessage"
    show={this.state.Result.showMessge}
>
    {this.state.Result.message}
</ToggleDisplay>
```

But, of course, this just prints raw text.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not create your own `ToggleNavlinkDisplay` component with it's own ability to toggle it's own display (which is the `a` tag's parent presumably, or the `a` tag itself)?

Comment: I did think about that but there are maybe 6 different messages so creating 6 different components is not efficient, to me at least - some contain `<NavLink />`s, some don't

Comment: Can you do this? `<ToggleDisplay>Please <a href="/Register">Click Here</a><ToggleDisplay>` If that works, I would think you really only need two toggle components: The normal one, plus one that allowed you to use the embedded navlink. I don't know React to know if that will work, but unless they're six totally different types of responses, I would guess you only need the two.

Comment: Nope, I mentioned that in the OP, if it worked as planned that would blow the SPA out as it causes a page change, plus, it would actually just render the text  `Please <a href="/Register">Click Here</a>` to the screen

Comment: That's not what I meant (injecting it as string), but I don't know enough about React. Good luck.

Comment: Since I'm a crow and I like shiny things, came across this searching for ad hoc components: [Higher-order Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html). FWIW.

Comment: Thanks, I love the last paragraph opening line `This is not a perfect solution by any means.` They should have put that as a `tl;dr` at the start! I love shiny too, hence why playing with React, not 100% convinced on it as this seems like a pretty trivial every day need...

Comment: I think you're fine with `innerHTML` as long as you're 100% sure userland data won't leak into it (Crisco the Partially Blind Omniscient says good luck with that). I think they meant that using HOCs with `refs` and the workarounds aren't great. The approach of a HOC seems fine, unless you've got a lot of whatever `refs` are already.

Comment: But `innerHTML` fails with rendering components e.g. `<NavLink />` so it's a non starter